# Relationship between stochastic processes and the chromatic number from graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, coloring

Is there a relationship between the chromatic number or the way the chromatic number is computed in graph theory to brownian motions or stochastic processes in general?

As in, is there a way where concepts from graph theory are applied to find the smallest amount of stocks one has to buy to "win" still?

I faintly remember reading one such comment which hinted this was the case but i can't find any literature on this. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Relationship between stochastic processes and the chromatic number from graph theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/365083).